Does FAT32 cluster size makes a difference in performance, for Nintendo 3DS with a big MicroSD?
A larger cluster size shall lead to faster read/write speeds because the system can access larger chunks of data at once. However, there are compatibility problems on 3DS, reported for cluster size other than 32kb. I do wonder if there are any noticeable differences for different cluster size.

The cluster size mattered with spinny disks; the access time is complete non-issue with flash media. What I found an actual problem is factory-formatted SD cards have the clusters sized such that just a having a couple hundred files makes it impossible to create new files despite the card being 80% empty. Running the card through Windows format, with default settings for fat32 provided a much more sane behavior.
